# Laravel route giving undefined variable even though route list match up

Tags: php, laravel, url-routing

I have a view that creates a group of Gallery photo's and save them via a model.  What I am trying to bring in additionally is a way to Delete and Update new images.  But for some reason my form route is giving me an `Undefined variable home` when declaring the route to the Update method in the Controller.
View form route declaration:

```php
{!! Form::open(['url' => route('admin.home.update', ['id' => $home->id]), 'method' => 'put', 'id' => 'amend_form', 'enctype'=>"multipart/form-data"])!!}
```

Resource update Route list:

```
y                          | web,admin
|        | PUT|PATCH | admin/home/{home}    | admin.home.update               |App\HttpControllers\Admin\AdminHomeController@update
```

Route resource declared:

```php
Route::resource('home', 'AdminHomeController');
```

Controller Update method

```php
public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }
```

Can someone please point me in the right direction to solve the reason for the error?

Comment: Are you passing the variable $home from your index() in AdminHomeController to your view? If not, then you will get the error since your view expects it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$home->id` is not defined.
If `$home->id` is undefined then you need to define it, to tell your `Model` / `DB` which id will be updated.

Comment: Still receiving the same `Undefined variable: home` error pointing to the view source as origin of error `(View: localhost/site/resources/views/admin/home/index.blade.php)`

Comment: What's about `route('admin.home.update',  $home->id)` Any improve?

Comment: If not work then `$home->id` has not defined. Check it with `route('admin.home.update', ['home' => 1])` now what happen?

Comment: I want to send the form data to the update method.  How do I declare the method Parameters in the form?  If the `$home->id` is undefined.  Do I just send the bare `$request` to store and update from there.

Comment: Great. The page loaded with parameter `['home' => 1]`.

Comment: if `$home->id` is undefined then you need to define it, to tell your `Model/DB` which id will be updated.

Comment: I see know.  I misunderstood how the method worked. So on choosing a record to update there should be a redirect to a page where the id is passed as the last parameter in the url.  So preloading data from database and retrieving via jquery will not work.  I have to check if `isset($home->id)` via ajax before showing form.  Thanks.  Just add your last comment to your answer and I will mark it as the solution.

Comment: By the way `['id' => 1]` also worked? Instead of `['home' => 1]`?